# In React, Is there a way to communicate between two components in both sides (duplex) using React Context API?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want to both send and receive states from a component with another component. Is there a method to perform that using React Context API?

Note: I don't prefer to use Redux instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. If you were using props, two way communication would be achieved by a parent component passing down both some data and a function. The child component uses the function to communicate back to the parent. The same thing can be done with context, only now the components aren't direct parent and child.

```
export const ExampleContext = React.createContext();

const ExampleProvider = (props) => {
  const state = useState('something');

  return (
    <ExampleContext.Provider value={state}>
      {props.children}
    </ExampleContext.Provider>
  )
}

const ExampleConsumer = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useContext(ExampleContext);

  // Do something with the value, or call setValue to let the provider know it needs to update.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But using props, it is hard to communicate among siblings, grand parents ect. I just want to know using React Context API

Comment: If you have a specific case that you want details on, feel free to include that information in your question.

Comment: Problem solved. But it is not clear when ExampleProvider is called. Can you please explain.

Comment: My code never renders the ExampleProvider. I know almost nothing about what you're trying to do, so i have no way to give specific advice. Render the provider somewhere up the component tree, render the consumer somewhere down the component tree.